# Match character from a group of characters in php

Tags: php

Is there any way to check character from eg

```
<?php
$chars='a'||'f'||'h'||'k';
$char2match='f';
if($char2match ==$chars )
{
echo'hello';
}
?>
```

here `$char2match ==$chars` is for matching only one string from a,f,h,k

Comment: `$chars='a'||'f'||'h'||'k';` --- what's this? Have you checked `var_dump($chars);`?

Comment: Why don't you *look* at your code before you ask for it to be fixed? it's not even valid!

Comment: no it was not valid but i was not knowing how to do it now problem solved.

Comment: @MightyPork: what do you mean by "valid"? The given code **is** syntactically correct

Comment: I was, among other stuff, referring to the missing space after `echo`. But now I tried to run it, and it seems PHP is benevolent enough to allow this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need array for chars collection and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) function that checks if a particular element is in the array:

```
$chars = array('a', 'f', 'h', 'k');
if (in_array('f', $chars)) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: My bet is `strstr('afhk', $char2match)` _is_ faster still, though

Comment: also for convert array you can use $arr=explode('||',$chars);

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: my bet is that ASM is faster PHP still, though :-)

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma: `$chars` is not a string in OP's example

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's:

```
if(preg_match('/[afhk]/', $char2match))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple things, as far as strings go...

```
    $chars='a'||'f'||'h'||'k';
    $chars2match = 'f';
    if(strpos($chars, $chars2match)) {
        print 'hello';
    }
```

OR

```
    if(strstr($chars, $chars2Match)) {
        print 'hello';
    }
```

OR CASE INSENSITIVE

```
    if(stristr($chars, $chars2Match) {
         print 'hello';
    }
```

Those are a couple easy ways to search for characters in a string.

Comment: `$chars` isn't a string in the OPs example

Comment: It's a double pipe delimited string...what do you mean it isn't a string? An array may be a better choice, but according to the syntax provided, it is a string.